# Carbonite has taken over my iMac

Tags: macos, backup, carbonite

I used Carbonite to back up 75GB on my iMac.  I also created a folder on my iMac to copy files to, from an external hard drive and then use Carbonite to back up from there.  And THEN thinking I had everything safely backed up and, in order to make room on my hard drive I DELETED some of those files, and instead of increasing disk space..my disk space has shrunk to 2GB... I know, I know..you can't use Carbonite like that, but now I have two questions.  1) What is the explanation for the decrease in disk space even though I have deleted about 20GB of those backed up files from my hard drive? It must have something to do with the way Carbonite references backed up files, And  2) Is there a way to extricate myself from this situation?

Comment: When you say "my disk space has shrunk to 2GB", I assume you are referring to your *free* disk space. Right?

Comment: More information is needed. What was your local drive's free space before moving the external drive's files, after the migration to local drive, and what was it after Carbonite backed up those files? Carbonite doesn't make file references, it makes an actual copy on their servers.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas for how to extricate yourself (some perhaps too obvious):

- Did you check your Trash?
- Download and run [Grand Perspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/) to get a view on which file and directories are taking up the most space.

Answer (score 0):

Carbonite holds onto all deleted files for 30 days. You should call them and ask about deleting those files sooner, if your certain you no longer need them.